# Haskell adding two lists using foldr

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I know that in Haskell, there is `intercalate` function that concats two lists.

```
intercalate ", " ["Hello", "world"]
```

would give: `"Hello, world"`

I am trying to concat two lists using `foldr`.

But since I am new to Haskell, I am unsure how to do this.

I believe the function is suppose to be something like:

```
inters n xs = foldr (\x acc -> x ++ str ++ acc) "" xs
```

This gives the result : `"Hello, world, "`
where the comma and the space gets added at the end also.

How do I make it so that the function only adds in-between the elements of the list and not at the ends?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a foldl with https://github.com/rShetty/functional-go/blob/master/functional.go, no foldr though. This example might help: https://play.golang.org/p/BCMbiTRLfo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are functions `foldl1` and `foldr1` that you can use:

```
foldl1 (\s1 s2 -> s1 ++ ", " ++ s2) ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
foldr1 (\s1 s2 -> s1 ++ ", " ++ s2) ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
```